# wp_insert_post memory consumption

Tags: wp-insert-post, memory

I'm using **wp_insert_post** in a loop to insert 500 posts in a new WP install.  It works quickly, and memory usage is from 25M to 28M.  The next run of a second batch of 500 posts, takes the memory from 25M to 178M.  So the memory usage seems to be based on how many posts are already in the table.  A third run of 500 posts exhausts the available memory.  What is being stored to increase the memory that I can cleanup?

Comment: did u solve the problem ?

Comment: maybe try define( 'SAVEQUERIES', false );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some profiling, it was the 5k+ queries being stored in the $wpdb->queries array.

Comment: That doesn’t really _answer_ anything. Why are so many queries stored? How did you resolve that?

Comment: Unless SAVEQUERIES is defined as false, WP will save every query it makes in $wpdb->queries.  I mentioned I was running 500+ inserts in a loop, that adds up to a lot of queries.  Those queries take up space in memory as the loop progresses.